# How to create a directory in "user.home"?

Tags: java, file, directory

How would you create a directory inside the user's home?

I know how to create a normal directory, but how do you set a path for it with `user.home`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
boolean success = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "directory_name").mkdirs();
```

Comment: There is no `mkdirs` in `File`

Comment: Look again. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()

Answer (score 1):

**[System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)**

*To Improving the post answer! gathered all the information and put it together.*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myDirectory = "Yash"; // user Folder Name
    String path = getUsersHomeDir() + File.separator + myDirectory ;

    if (new File(path).mkdir()) {
        System.out.println("Directory is created!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
    }
    getOSInfo();
}
public static void getOSInfo(){
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String osbitVersion = System.getProperty("os.arch");
    String jvmbitVersion = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");

    System.out.println(os + " : "+osbitVersion+" : "+jvmbitVersion);
}
public static String getUsersHomeDir() {
    String users_home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    return users_home.replace("\\", "/"); // to support all platforms.
}
```

*To print all available properties.*

```
for (Entry<Object, Object> e : System.getProperties().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue())); 
}
```